# Webhook support for (non-root) Drive Items Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm wondering if Webhook subscription for non-root Drive Items will be added.
Specifically I'm asking of subscriptions to Group Drive items, so that functionality like SharePoint's 'Alert me' when file changes can be implemented.

Question is for someone from Graph development team as I could not find info in documentation, and the documentation itself points to stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not something that's currently on the roadmap; but please submit it to our [UserVoice](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer) page so that others can vote on it, too.